# Add header to every file in project setting (gcc -include)

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, ide, eclipse-cdt

I have a project which use **gcc -include file.h**

As gcc documentation say, this ensures that file.h is included in every file which is compiled this way (meaning like there was #include "file.h" in every other files).

Now I have imported this project into eclipse and I set up the include path where that file is but can't figure out how to do something like gcc -include in eclipse project setting. The result of this is that in editor I have a LOT of "*Symbol xy could not be resolved*" but the project compiles just fine.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So you just need `file.h` seen from the indexer? I think that can be done adding the header file in the Paths and Symbols properties dialog, but I'm not sure if you can add a specific file.

Comment: I tried that but it did not help, I think that Paths there are equivalent of gcc -Ipath. Yes I need only that file.h to be seen from indexed. Also I tried setting indexed to index all header (because the file.h is in path I have added in the Paths and Symbols) but that also did not helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the **`CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings`** on a project-by-project basis.

- Go to **`Project` -> `Properties` -> `C/C++ General` -> `Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.`**
- Select the **`Providers`** tab.
- Select **`CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings`**
- Unselect **`Use global provider shared between projects`**
- Add the required GCC flags to the **`Command to get compiler specs:`** input box

(see highlighted text in image below)

[image]

You probably want to click **`Store entries in project settings folder`**

Comment: For completeness, the more direct way would be to just add file.h to the Paths and Symbols properties dialog / Include files tab.